# How to have Hibernate create tables on startup?

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I am using Hibernate with HSQLDB and I have noticed that when the application starts up, no tables get created in HSQLDB.  It's not until the first select or the first insert that all the tables get created in HSQLDB.  Is there any way to have all the tables get created when the application starts up?

EDIT in reply to Pangea:

I modified our hibernate cfg xml file so that it includes the following:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

But the tables still do not get created when the server starts up.  They only get created after the first insert or select.  You mentioned that the tables will be created during the creation of the Hibernate session factory.  Our code does not call the Configuration.buildSessionFactory() until an insert or a select is performed.  Is there any way to create the tables prior to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that is how hibernate generally works. It is started when it is called. You could create an empty constructor and have it called at the beginning of your application or have it started up within your web.xml is you are using a web application with a servlet call.

If you don't let your program know that you want hibernate to start at the beginning of you start of the program it will not create it until it has been told to or is needed for the SessionFactory.

You have all the correct syntax from what I can tell. Just ensure else in the beginning of the program that you want it to be called earlier.

Hibernate.org has a create example of HibernateUtil.class which you can modify to add an empty constructor to call upon.

Hope this helps with starting up Hibernate at the beginning of your application.

Comment: OK I made a call to Configuration.buildSessionFactory() at the start of the program and it works.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem man! Here are some helpful links. First one is Hibernate.org tutorial for HibernateUtil class with XML Config. Second is a great youtube series with Annotated Classes and Annotated Session Factories. (Little extra homework for you) it will be embed in your brain, like it is mine. :)[link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/)[link](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4AFF701184976B25)

Answer (score 4):

Add the below property to your hibernate cfg file so that tables are auto created during the creation of hibernate session factory.

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```